# Centered textbox with an offset label?

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox centered on a page. What I would like to have is an error label display to the right of it, if necessary, and keep the textbox centered on the page. The page contains a Panel, which is centering the entire page.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlStart" runat="server" CssClass="center">
...    
...
...   
            <tr>
                <td>    
                    <div>                                
                        <input type="text" id="pName" name="pName" runat="server" class="pName" style="color:#7A0000;width:33%;" 
                               value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />                
                         <asp:Label ID="pNameValidationLabel" style="width:33%;" name="pName" runat="server" Text="*Please enter your name." class="pName" visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    </div>                                               
                </td>
            </tr>
```

On page load, the textbox is centered properly. but when the visibility of the pNameValidate Label appears, it tries to force both object into the Center. 
Is there a way for the textbox to be centered and the label off centered, to the right?

Many thanks for looking.

Comment: try with `float:right` on the class `pName`

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add text-align:right; to the style tag in the pName element.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a table and this quickly provided me what I needed...

```
<tr>
     <td>
                    <table width="100%">                    
                        <tr>
                            <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="33%">
                            <div id="shaker">
                                <input type="text" id="pName" autocomplete="false" clientidmode="Static" name="pName" runat="server" class="pName" 
                                    value="Please Enter Your Name Here" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />                
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>  
                </td>
            </tr>
```